# Getting cloudflared all of a sudden, why?

Tags: vpn, cloudflare

I used tor with success for a long time, then all of a sudden, almost every site would give me the "one more step" cloudflare page, after a few months this stopped, and tor worked fine again for months, but now it's back.

It's like someone flicked a switch. The only thing I can think of is my virgin media ip recently changed after a connection problem I had to call them about. But I use a vpn. But thinking about it, I'm sure the problem started before my ip change.

What the hell happened to my tor connection?

Comment: Have you already browsed thru your cookies?

Comment: I don't know what that means. The problem exists on a brand new tor browser.

Comment: What's your VPN set-up with respect to Tor? Are you chaining your VPN after you exit the Tor network? Have you tried without your VPN in the chain?

Comment: I open my vpn and I think everything routes through that, not sure, I know my normal browser does. Not sure how to "chain" it. And yes I have tried with out the vpn. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using an exit node that was tagged as a "dealing bot traffic" one. The problem lies deep in tor exit node setup guide. The guide says that you should expose the fact, that you're running an exit node via info page on port 80 and so forth

> https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-relay-debian.html.en

states clear :

> 9. If you run an exit relay (great!), don't miss out on our Exit Guidelines, including setting your reverse DNS hostname to make it obvious that you're a Tor exit relay, and serving the Tor exit notice page on your DirPort.

In My Humble Opinion this is wrong : it makes censorship supporter's tasks easy to perform. Try to use another exit nodes.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare is blocking most (or all?) Tor Exit node for everyone having enabled even on the most minimal security setting. Only if this setting is completely switched off CloudFlare won't show that CAPTCHA.

Since many websites use the CloudFlare these days you will be presented this page.

You might want to contact either the website owner or CloudFlare to complain about this. Website owners may not have any intention and only left CloudFlare on default settings. They could switch it off.

I don't think the security benefit is too big. Either your website is insecure and someone will exploit it, maybe simply without Tor or connecting through a VPN or your website is secure and the CAPTCHA only annoys people.

Also even with security settings completely disabled all the requests will still go through CloudFlare, which may prevent certain DOS-attacks. So that benefit remains to website owners. Maybe they should be informed.